# Is there a way to transfer indexes and views from MySQL to SQL Developer using Pentaho?

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper, pentaho-spoon

I am a student and new to my role at the BI team here at my university. I was asked to my data from our MySQl database to our Oracle database. I was able to move the data over but now I am trying to figure out how to move the views and indexes over. I tried researching an an answer here but I only found something from SQL Server. I am using Toad to access our MySQL data and SQLDeveloper to access Oracle and then Pentaho is the intermediary.

Comment: you just need to re-create them. Generate CREATE statements for the mysql versions and then try to run them in Oracle. Bear in mind the syntax maybe different in some cases so it might require a bit of a re-write.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that and I'll watch out for the SQL differences. Thanks!